# How to get users' shared links by using Facebook open graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, youtube

I have a web application, where users have to login with their facebook accounts. I want to get user's shared youtube links on her/his timeline, when s/he is logging into the system.

I think open graph api does not support such feature. I do not know it is possible or not.

How can I get this information?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot filter the timeline for specific data, but you can narrow down the number of possible records to process by using the "links" path component:

https://graph.facebook.com/userID/links?access_token=AT

This will return all links the user posted on his timeline. Loop through all returned results, search the link field, if it contains "youtube" you have a video.

Keep in mind that even you set a high limit (like 2000 entries) you need to deal with paging.

Hope that helps: Lars

Answer (score 1):

**Note:  links field is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher**

It seems, not possible to get shared links from /posts endpoint too. Because there we can get the message only. Nothing about the shared link.

Comment: any clue how this works now to get all links? I have the same issue.